# Creating a new dataframe with averages from another dataframe with multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have fish count data and am trying to create a new dataframe using averages of the measurements based on conditions of two different columns. here is my data:

```
df <- structure(list(SITE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    ZONE = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CREST", "INNER_FLAT", "MID_FLAT", 
    "OUTER_FLAT", "SLOPE"), class = "factor"), C_TOTAL = c(44L, 
    7L, 20L, 14L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 28L, 24L, 31L, 12L, 
    33L, 6L, 16L, 33L, 75L, 21L, 60L, 81L, 37L, 89L, 21L, 35L, 
    71L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 23L, 0L, 5L, 11L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 
    0L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 42L), C_M2 = c(0.210465706, 0.029861994, 
    0.090324177, 0.066599319, 0, 0.022092452, 0.011750593, 0.015245519, 
    0.004710433, 0.033111594, 0.155094195, 0.110576495, 0.193659068, 
    0.059152822, 0.192379108, 0.047800772, 0.08917095, 0.141336411, 
    0.402538785, 0.130438337, 0.315206235, 0.460746849, 0.278643938, 
    0.467754275, 0.192830321, 0.119928472, 0.411502497, 0.015370489, 
    0.005150184, 0, 0, 0.034651441, 0.067824733, 0, 0.009805851, 
    0.034844309, 0.010614352, 0.004131048, 0.01850898, 0, 0, 
    0.029195413, 0.021409016, 0.030498145, 0.172406074), TRANS_A = c(209.0601875, 
    234.411677, 221.4246571, 210.2123593, 226.6158348, 181.0573136, 
    170.2041767, 196.7791332, 212.294701, 241.6072127, 180.5354478, 
    217.0443184, 160.0751279, 202.8643689, 171.536298, 125.5209863, 
    179.4306337, 233.485481, 186.3174499, 160.9956132, 190.3515643, 
    175.801528, 132.7859497, 190.2708425, 108.9040348, 291.8406241, 
    172.5384427, 325.2986863, 388.3356059, 303.1957479, 261.1574528, 
    288.5882879, 339.1093313, 239.1118021, 509.89965, 315.6899993, 
    282.6362022, 242.0693453, 270.1391425, 294.8864591, 321.2013381, 
    274.0156514, 326.9650539, 196.7332763, 243.6109069), SCARID_T = c(35L, 
    4L, 4L, 13L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 20L, 12L, 17L, 5L, 20L, 
    6L, 6L, 18L, 63L, 11L, 41L, 75L, 34L, 89L, 14L, 33L, 68L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 22L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    6L, 0L, 4L, 42L), ACAN_T = c(4L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), SIG_T = c(5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 7L, 14L, 7L, 13L, 0L, 7L, 13L, 
    5L, 2L, 11L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 2L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-45L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to average all the measurements by each zone, but also according to site. So I want anew data frame where each site has one measurement for each zone.
Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(SITE, ZONE) %>% 
    summarise(
        across(where(is.numeric), mean)
    )
# A tibble: 15 x 8
# Groups:   SITE [3]
   SITE  ZONE       C_TOTAL    C_M2 TRANS_A SCARID_T ACAN_T  SIG_T
   <fct> <fct>        <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 1     CREST        20    0.0996     213.   12      4.33   3.67 
 2 1     INNER_FLAT    3    0.0111     265.    0.333  0.333  2.33 
 3 1     MID_FLAT      2.33 0.00684    339.    0      0      2.33 
 4 1     OUTER_FLAT   52    0.283      179.   38.3    7.67   6    
 5 1     SLOPE        23.7  0.110      222.   14.3    5      4.33 
 6 2     CREST        25.3  0.148      178.   14      0     11.3  
 7 2     INNER_FLAT    2.67 0.00973    297.    2      0.667  0    
 8 2     MID_FLAT     11    0.0342     296.   10.7    0.333  0    
 9 2     OUTER_FLAT   69    0.402      166.   66      0.667  2.33 
10 2     SLOPE         6    0.0296     206.    5.67   0      0.333
11 3     CREST        18.3  0.0928     179.   10      1.67   6.67 
12 3     INNER_FLAT   18.3  0.0748     256.   15.3    0      3    
13 3     MID_FLAT      5.33 0.0149     355.    3.33   1.67   0.333
14 3     OUTER_FLAT   42.3  0.241      191.   38.3    0.333  3.67 
15 3     SLOPE         2    0.0106     193.    1      0      1
```